# Activity with ProgressBar -> Service -> AsyncTask for downloading - but how to update the progress?

Tags: android, service, progress-bar

this is the current state/situation: I have an Activity which binds a Service which creates AsyncTasks which downloads various web resources. That works well, but of course the ProgressBar shows nothing.

Previously i had an Activity which created an AsyncTask which downloaded some stuff. The AsyncTask got the View which holds the ProgressBar. So i could update the progress using onProgressUpdate and publishProgress. Obviously this doesn't work any longer because I have no reference to the ProgressBar.

So, do you have any idea on how to update the progress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have the `Service` notify the then-running `Activity` about the progress from `onProgressUpdate()`. That could be via a broadcast `Intent`, or via a callback object registered by the `Activity` (and unregistered when the `Activity` is destroyed, such as on a screen rotation).

Comment: Thanks. I have now a class ProgressReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver. The Intents from onProgressUpdate() get there and i can read the progress out of them. But how can I update the ProgressBar?
Sorry, i don't get it :(

Comment: Make that ProgressReceiver be an inner class of your Activity, registered via registerReceiver() and unregistered via unregisterReceiver(). Then, ProgressReceiver can just call setProgress() or incrementProgressBy() on your ProgressBar.

Comment: @Commonsware dont u think Broadcasting something every second will consume memory or  eat battery? like if i download some 10 mb file and have network bandwidth of 100kbps, then it will going to broadcast for 100 times... rather i prefer a Interface between service and activity.. is that would be lightweighted??

Comment: @HimanshuMori: This question and answer are nearly seven years old. "dont u think Broadcasting something every second will consume memory or eat battery?" -- not compared to the download itself. The download will take orders of magnitude more power, and the memory implications here are negligible. That being said, nowadays, I would recommend an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus), to somewhat improve efficiency but more importantly improve security.

Answer (score 11):

Very nice explained indeed just missing the example :) 
I went throw it and here it is.

```
public class Detail extends Activity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(DownloadService.CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(intent.getFlags());
            }
        }
    };

    // Flag if receiver is registered 
    private boolean mReceiversRegistered = false;
    // Define a handler and a broadcast receiver
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Register Sync Recievers
      IntentFilter intentToReceiveFilter = new IntentFilter();
      intentToReceiveFilter.addAction(DownloadService.CUSTOM_INTENT);
      this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentToReceiveFilter, null, mHandler);
      mReceiversRegistered = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      // Make sure you unregister your receivers when you pause your activity
      if(mReceiversRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
        mReceiversRegistered = false;
      }
    }
}








public class DownloadService extends Service {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = DownloadService.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<Download> downloads = new ArrayList<Download>();
    private int currentPosition;
    public static final String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
    private Context ctx;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        ctx = getApplicationContext();
        return mBinder;
    }


    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... _url) {
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, CLASS_NAME + " Start the background GetNewsTask \nURL :" + _url[0]);
            int count;
            File finalFile = new File(sdcardPath + Constants.APK_LOCAL_PATH + "/" + splitName(_url[0]));
            try {
                if (!finalFile.exists()) {
                    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, CLASS_NAME + " Donwloading apk from the Web");
                    URL url = new URL(_url[0]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                    // progress bar
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    // downlod the file
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    File dir = new File(sdcardPath + Constants.APK_LOCAL_PATH);
                    if (!dir.exists())
                        dir.mkdirs();
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(sdcardPath + Constants.APK_LOCAL_PATH + "/" + splitName(_url[0]));
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } else {
                    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, CLASS_NAME + " Apk in SDcard");
                    publishProgress(100);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
            i.setFlags(progress[0]);
            ctx.sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }

    private String splitName(String url) {
        String[] output = url.split("/");
        return output[output.length - 1];
    }

    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "es.tempos21.sync.client.ProgressReceiver";

    private final IDownloadService.Stub mBinder = new IDownloadService.Stub() {

        public void downloadAsynFile(String url) throws DeadObjectException {
            try {
                DownloadFile d = new DownloadFile();
                d.execute(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, CLASS_NAME + " " +e.getMessage());         }
        }


        }
};


interface IDownloadService {

    void downloadAsynFile(String url);    
}
```

Comment: it has when has publish, maybe now with the API changes may need some polish.

Comment: The `BroadcastReceiver` is a good idea but I would suggest using `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support Library. It only sends `Intent`s within YOUR application so it is more secure and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can show progress just as easily via a Toast, which obviates all of the UI concerns:

```
public class foo extends Service {
private Toast toast;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    ctxt = getApplicationContext();
    toast = Toast.makeText(ctxt, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    ...
}

public void functionCalledByYourAsyncWithUpdates(String progress){
    toast.setText (progress);
    toast.show;
}
}
```